# iOS Coreplot - less than equal to symbol

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am using `ScatterPlot` of `CorePlot` and would like to create a legend. The legend should contain a *less than equal to* symbol. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It can draw any character you put into the legend entry titles.

Comment: Can you give some sample code as to how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `title` or the `attributedTitle` property of the plot to the text you want displayed in the legend. This string can include a "≤" symbol or any other valid character.

Comment: I would like to know how to obtain that symbol. I mean in the keyboard  we get <=. Should we use some latex symbol?

Comment: On the Mac, you can type it with **Option-,**.

Comment: its amazing! I did not know of such options. I can use many more symbols from my keyboard now!